# Manually downgrading iOS 14.1 to 13.1

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade my iPhone from `14.1` to `13.3` in order to jailbreak it using checkm8, since checkm8 supports up to iOS `13.3`. I have currently downloded `13.3` IPSW, but since it is not signed, I am not able to install it to my iPhone using iTunes. For that reason I though that I might be able to downgrade it by bypassing iTunes using alternative methods such as tools like tinyumbrella. But unfortunately, because of bad programming behind the tool, tinyumbrella doesn't even start. So what I wonder is that what alternative apps can I use for manually downgrading the firmware, and is it even really possible to downgrade an iPhone to an unsigned IPSW version.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: All the answers to the question posted above are answered years ago. Regarding how quickly technology changes, I believe we can get fresh answers here under my question. So answers to the above question doesn't completely anwer my question nor satisfy.

Comment: We close as duplicate to point everyone to the canonical question. Putting bounty on the old question if you think a new version has a different answer is always acceptable.